# What could be the cause of my phone going into safe mode?

Tags: huawei, safe-mode

I have a Huawei phone and I have been using it for several years but recently it sometimes ( very rarely) goes into safe mode. The android version is 6.

I do not have any external cover so no buttons are being accidentally pressed.